# Implement HMAC in Azure Function HTTP Trigger

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, hmac

I was asked to implement HMAC in Azure Function that receives web-hooks requests but I don't find documentations that give me an idea of how to do that. Any suggestion would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something an azure function can do natively. You'll need to write some custom code to do the following:

1. Retrieve the HMAC signature sent from the webhook sender. This will likely be sent as a header on the `HttpRequestData` object you receive (assuming this is azure functions v4).
2. Compute a hash of the body of the request, using the key that is shared between you and the webhook sender. You can use the `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256` class to do this.:

```cs
public string ComputeHMAC(string data, string key)
{
    var dataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
    var keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

    var hmacHash = HMACSHA256.HashData(keyBytes, dataBytes);

    var hashSB = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hmacHash.Length; i++)
    {
        hashSB.Append(hmacHash[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return hashSB.ToString();
}
```

3. Compare your computed hash with the hash received from the webhook sender. If the hashes do not match, you need to reject the webhook request.

You could take this a step further and write an HMAC middleware if you need to do this in different azure functions.

Comment: When you phrase "body of the request" you meant to first convert the body into a string like this code below (I am pasting) and then pass it to the method in your answer?

`var bodyStream = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
    bodyStream.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    var bodyText = bodyStream.ReadToEnd();
    return bodyText;`